# draw linear-gradient line chart in highchart.js based on another series

Tags: charts, highcharts, linear-gradients

I want to plot a chart just like this photo.
[image: my pattern chart]

but I don't know how to create gradient color on the price line according to days until halving.
this is a sample of my row data:

[image: row data]

Comment: Could you share sample data? How the gradient line data look like and where does it come from?

Comment: second img shows sample data. gradient color comes from "daysTillHalving". it rages between 0 and about 1400

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the `colorAxis` feature/module to achieve the wanted result.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gsu8xhob/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

---

EDIT:

Oh, my mistake, it seems that the `minColor` and `maxColor` values must be a HEX or rgb.

Comment: tnx but in my browser the color of the all points are blue and same!

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian check edit

Comment: tnx, now its work for me. But it takes the color from the main data(y-axis). I want to take it from third series of data.

Comment: Setting the `colorAxis` as null in the main series config should fix the problem. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ckdjnyo/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.colorAxis

Comment: TNX a lot. I have two problem with your previous code. you solved the first that I don't mention it. I want to set the color range based on another data series. You can see the refrence chart here: https://studio.glassnode.com/metrics?a=BTC&category=&m=indicators.StockToFlowRatio&zoom=all

Comment: I have 3 series of data.
one that must be in a solid color (I set it by colorAxis: null)
second must be colorful. third series define the color of the second series.

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian please reproduce this scenario on the jsFiddle